# Vue.js: Passing environment variables to a vue.js application

Tags: vue.js

I'm running a vue.js application in a Docker container. I have some configuration set via environment variables (e.g. API base url). I want to be able to use these variables in my application in browser. How can I pass them?

I tried to add these variables to one of the config/*.env.js files like that (config/dev.env.js):

```
module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  backendBase: process.env.BACKEND_BASE
})
```

Then I run application using `npm run dev` but `process.env` object is always empty (`NODE_ENV` is also not available)

Comment: The environment variables are available at the runtime of where the build is executed. You can't have an environment variable be exported to the bundle that is executed in the (browser) client because that is executed in the browser.

Comment: @acdcjunior I understand that the only time I can have access to the env vars is the build time. But isn't that possible to bake them at this moment in the resulting build? If so I'll be forced to use some hacks in my Dockerfile...

Comment: Are you using vue-cli? If so, what version?

Comment: @acdcjunior I do. `vue -V` says it's 2.9.3

Comment: I have tested adding to `config/dev.env.js` and it worked for me. Have you tried it in a brand new cli project?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the exact same problem recently.  If you are running the dev server using a watcher I think it doesn't pick the config change up correctly.  I stopped my dev server, rebuilt production as well (no idea if that helps but just in case) and then started the dev server up again and all was ok.

To access the above settings you should be able to use process.env in your code

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think only variables prefixed with `VUE_APP` get packaged up by Vue.

From: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

> Note that only variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically
>   embedded into the client bundle with `webpack.DefinePlugin`.

I tested locally.

`.env` in root:

```
APP_TEST=foo
VUE_APP_TEST=bar
```

In `main.js`:

```js
// imports and other stuff

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');

console.log(process.env.APP_TEST, 'APP_TEST');
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_TEST, 'VUE_APP_TEST');
```

Output:

```
undefined APP_TEST 
bar VUE_APP_TEST
```

You'll need to run another build if you make changes to your envvars.